# data export from site is in lines, how to put it in table form

Tags: microsoft-excel, export, import, statistics

I exported some data from a nutritions tracking website to use in excel and eventually in SPSS for analysis. However the data is exported in lines/rows. I need it to be in table form so I can use it of course, or is there perhaps a way of using the data in this form? it just seems inefficient because it's hard to tell things from each other. is this form of export by any chance meant for import in statistical software? I feel like I am missing something. I don't think the developers would have made an export in this format for no reason, there must be some logic behind it. see link attached for excel file, this is an export of 1 day data just for experiment purposes, the dataset I will be using is bigger.

Edit (solved): I found the missing link. the export from the website is in .csv format. Needed to tweak some setting while importing the csv in excel in order to get the data show in rows and columns.

thank you to whomever was my spiritual excel guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite its `.xlsx` file extension, you actually downloaded a comma-separated file. When opening in, e.g., Notepad, its contents look like:

```
Date,Energy (kcal),Alcohol (g),Ash (g),Caffeine (mg),Water (g),...
2018-12-30,815.60,0.00,5.82,0.00,1179.90,0.51,...
```

On Windows, if the regional settings in your system's preferences match this format, then Excel would import this automatically when double-clicking. In your case, you'll need to import this manually. See Microsoft's [help op Import or export text (.txt or .csv) files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba).